# Downloading a file via Requests.get(url) raises socket.error: [Errno 10013]

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to download a file from a Python program using `requests` module.

If run the following :

```
self.proxy = {"http_proxy": "...", "https_proxy": "..."}
request = requests.get(
                file_url,
                allow_redirects=True,
                proxies=self.proxy,
                timeout=30
            )
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyPrograms\python_virtual_envs\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "D:\MyPrograms\python_virtual_envs\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "D:\MyPrograms\python_virtual_envs\3.10.5\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

But if I open `Gitbash` on the same computer, I'm able to download the same file via `wget` without any problem.

```
export http_proxy=...
export https_proxy=...
wget file_url
...                         0%[>                ]   7.49M  2.26MB/s    eta 6m 56s
```

So if it works in command line via `wget` but not in a Python program using `requests` module, I don't think that is something related to security rules at antivirus/firewall level on the computer. Besides I checked the events and there was no trace of blocking my Python program trying to access the Web.

Any idea? How I might be able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Instead of writing

```
self.proxy = {"http_proxy": "...", "https_proxy": "..."}
```

I had to write

```
self.proxy = {"http": "...", "https": "..."}
```